# AWS CodeCommit access denied while cloning

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, aws-codestar

*Recently* i set up and downloaded the repo by using the git credentials generated from AWS IAM user but then

- i deleted that AWS git generated key that i had used to clone the
  repo first time.

now

- i have generated another AWS git key but it is not asking me for the
  username and key instead i am getting

> **ERROR**

```
Cloning into 'myawsrepo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myawsrepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
MacBook-Pro:~ apple$
```

Comment: Can you follow the same instructions you used when configuring git to use the original credentials?

Comment: tried  but i am not getting prompted to enter the credentials again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Went to user in AWS IAM console
2. Deleted git credential
3. Deleted user credentials
4. Created new user credentials
5. Created new git credentials